# экспортированный из eclipse .jar файл не запускается

Tags: java, eclipse

я уже экспортировал этот проект до этого пару раз и все работало "на других компьютерах тоже" но сейчас нет, консоль жалуется что не может найти другие классы ни одного.

пытался найти решение в интернете но он выдает "как собирать проекты в apache ant" стоит изучать ant или эту проблему можно решить легче?

Comment: Библиотеки какие-нибудь подключали?

Comment: @post_zeew только стандартные JFrame,Timer,MouseListener и тд. все они были и в рабочих jar файлах. в консоли пишет что не может найти добустим static ClassName Name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "JFrame,Timer,MouseListener и тд."

Они не стандартные. Библиотеки с этими классами должны быть добавленны в classpath